# Sites 9 - Resolving does not work properly for static Component within a Region

Tags: sites-9, resolving

We have the following situation:

1. a Component "New Component" is is added to 2 Pages paired with a **static CT**: "Home" and "New Page"
2. on the Home Page, the Component is within a Region; on the New Page it is not
3. both Pages are published
4. when publishing (or clicking the Show Items To Publish on) the Component itself, both Pages [should be resolved](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-3B23A2DC-71A0-4F96-A164-9E594068B687&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-A589E3B1-E564-4409-B63C-CBF45D59CD6E.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-3B23A2DC-71A0-4F96-A164-9E594068B687&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dembedded&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1565645020541&currentQuery=embedded&currentScope=) but they're not! Only the one where the Components is not in a region is

See image below:
[image]

We have applied the "CM_9.0.0.13374" hotfix, see below, but this does not fix our issue. I am raising a ticket to SDL support, but I'm wondering, has anyone encountered this already and is a fix already available?

> ResolveContainingPages() method in TOM.NET and CoreService API does
>   not return Pages where Component Presentation is used if it was added
>   inside the Region. 'View on Site' button was not working properly due
>   to this problem.

**Update**

CM_9.0.0.13932 is also applied, but still the same behavior.

Comment: There is another hotfix in this area: CM_9.0.0.13932. Its description says "Resolving of Dynamic Component Presentations (DCP) works only for DCPs on the page; DCPs on nested regions are not resolved." Although it mentions dynamic component templates, you can give it a shot and check if it fixes the issue above.

Comment: I forgot to update the question, we have tried that already, but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed by SDL support as a bug. I will update this answer when the hotfix is released.